# How to access and show (print) objects stored in subList view created from an asList view object in Java

Tags: java, collections, sublist

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
      Card [] cardDeck= new Card[52];
      int i;
      for(i=0;i<52; i++ )
      {
      cardDeck[i]= new Card(i+"");
      }


      List<Card> cardList= Arrays.asList(cardDeck);

      List crd= cardList.subList(1, 10);

      for(int x=0; x<crd.size(); x++)
         System.out.println(crd.get(x).getName());  //here is the error, can't use 
                                                    //getName()
   }
};

class Card{

    private String name;

    public Card(String n)
    {
      name= n; 
    }

    public void setName(String n)
    {
       name=n; 
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: why isn't `List crd` generically typed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
List crd
```

to

```
List<Card> crd
```

the `subList` method supports the generic type of the list

Answer (score 1):

just cast each item to `Card`

```
for(int x=0; x<crd.size(); x++)
         System.out.println(((Card)crd.get(x)).getName());
```

Comment: can you explain why the casting is required?

Comment: as you declared `List crd` (this is same as `List<Object> crd`) each item in list stored in `Object` class, but you know that items are instance of `Card` class and you want to call some method that declared in `Card` so you must cast items from `Object` to `Card`, then you able to call `getName()` method,

Answer (score 0):

change

```
List  crd
```

by

```
 List <Card> crd
```